# Context select submenu

Tags: 7

I'm trying to enable a submenu item through context rules.

However, the Context is consistently trying to select only the top parent item, and not the submenu. I tried few times on completely clean installs with the same results.

Am I doing something wrong or it should be working this way?

How can I otherwise open a submenu item with context rules?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried "Menu Block" module?

Answer (score 1):

I am using a Menu Block module and Context to achieve a similar thing.

For conditions, I have this fire on a Content Type of Instructor Profile. I add Menu Block's blocks to region's One and Two accordingly.

[image]

And I use `Context` to automatically select the menu level for me

[image]